# Unable to get String value from UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift3, nsuserdefaults

Unable to get the string value stored in UserDefaults

```
var videoString = String()
```

In view did load

```
videoString = "http://site4brandz.com/cphp/26/uploads/oggy.mp4"
UserDefaults.standard.set(videoString as String, forKey: CurrentURL)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: CurrentURL))")
```

It's printing as follows:

```
Optional(http://site4brandz.com/cphp/26/uploads/oggy.mp4)
```

When I go back and checking the same string like

```
if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: CurrentURL) != nil) {
    print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: CurrentURL))")
    let runningSrtring  = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: CurrentURL)!
}
```

But now it's printing as `Optional(4.067826)` where did I made a mistake?

Comment: i think your problem is "CurrentURL", Make sure is value is same while set value and get the value

Comment: Use object for key and double check you key i think your key is not matching. You stored string with one key and getting with another key. Test with test key for eg  "MySavedKey" and get it print it again with "MySavedKey."

Comment: @ChanWarde yes you are right i have changed the key and modified as UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: CurrentURL)! and its worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Swift3

How about use `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: CurrentURL)!`

instead `UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: CurrentURL)!`

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: CurrentURL)! is this for setting? or getting??

Comment: @MaheshNarla that is getting function returning `String?` type

Answer (score 1):

**in Swift 2.3**

you can set value string in `UserDefaults`

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(videoString, forKey: CurrentURL)
```

By get the value from

```
if let string = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringforKey(CurrentURL) {
}
```

**In Swift 3**
you can set value string in `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(videoString, forKey: CurrentURL)
```

By get the value from `UserDefaults`

```
if let string = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: CurrentURL) {
}
```

Make sure your key "CurrentURL" have same Value

Comment: checkout my answer

Comment: Yes this is correct but its not worked for my scenario

Comment: I removed the `as? String` casts, they are not needed since the type is distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Change your UserDefaults set code:

from:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(videoString as String, forKey: CurrentURL)
```

to

```
if videoString {
  UserDefaults.standard.set(videoString!, forKey: CurrentURL)
}
```

and check the different!

Answer (score 1):

Try it with Swift3:

```
extension UserDefaults {

    func setValue(value: String, key: String) {
        set(value, forKey: key)
        synchronize()
    }

    func getValue(key: String) -> String {
        return string(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let videoString: String = "http://site4brandz.com/cphp/26/uploads/oggy.mp4"

UserDefaults.standard.setValue(value: videoString, key: CurrentURL)
```

and check it:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.getValue(key: CurrentURL))
```

Notice that i am using ***key*** as a `String`. Change **key**'s type  to **CurrentURL** type as you expect (e.g: `URL Type`, ...)